# firebase ios not working most of the times

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I just installed firebase on my ios app, swift 3. The problem is sometimes the notification never gets delivered, sometimes it works good but I never change the code in AppDelegate. What do you suggest me to edit, I cant find the problem.

PS. I dont receive notifications if im using app, only when im not using it I receive notifications, why?

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let lagFreeField = UITextField()
    self.window?.addSubview(lagFreeField)
    lagFreeField.becomeFirstResponder()
    lagFreeField.resignFirstResponder()
    lagFreeField.removeFromSuperview()


    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_,_ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self as? FIRMessagingDelegate

    } else {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge , .sound], categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    // [END register_for_notifications]

    FIRApp.configure()

    print("AppDelegate")

   IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tab = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
    self.window?.rootViewController = tab
    if Defaults.hasKey(.logged), let logged = Defaults[.logged], logged == true{
        APIRequest.username = Defaults[.username]!
        APIRequest.password = Defaults[.password]!
        let tab = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
        self.window?.rootViewController = tab

    } else {
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
        self.window?.rootViewController = controller
    }
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    print("Userinfo \(userInfo)")
}
```

Comment: Well, for starters, you're making calls to `FIRMessaging` _before_ you've successfully configured your library using `FIRApp.configure()`. I would move that configure line earlier and that will probably eliminate some of your issues...

Comment: If you want to turn off firebase push notifications when you LOG OUT - SIGN OUT please use: UIApplication.sharedApplication().unregisterForRemoteNotifications()

-- Re-enable it when login:
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the steps in firebase instructions and it will be ok. Firebase instructions:
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

One other great article to install firebase push notification from scratch to live app is made by AppCoda:

https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/